# In a .NET Core library. do I need to have DebugSymbols = true when I wish to embed my pdb symbols for a RELEASE build?

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget, pdb-files

I wish to embed my PDB debug file in my output DLL, in my .NET Core nuget library.

When I end up doing a RELEASE build, do I need to explicitly set `<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>` in my `csproj` file when I have `<DebugType>embedded</DebugType>` set and it's a RELEASE build (which is what I'll end up packing into a NuGet file?

For example: it has been [set/defined in the popular MiniProfile nuget package](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/e160a25e4578554b3c8fab9f8116b79abaa04837/src/Directory.build.props#L23-L24). Sure, I can add it and that means -all- configurations (DEBUG and RELEASE) will respect it. Just curious if I *need* it and how both of those settings relate to each other?

If I do NOT put `<DebugSymbols>` in, then on a RELEASE build, no pdb's will be made and therefore nothing gets embedded? If it's provided/true, then it gets generated AND it will be an embedded generation?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: Good question.  @Pure.Krome did you ever figure this out?